# Python: transformar \xf3 en ó con la función "encode"

Tags: python, utf-8

estoy trabajando con una librería de Twitter que descarga tweets y permite su posterior tratamiento.

El problema es que los acentos y otros caracteres especiales me los muestra se la siguiente forma:

```
La aplicaci\xf3n de un modelo educativo
```

en lugar de

```
La aplicación de un modelo educativo
```

He estado investigando por los foros y he encontrado una solución que sería:

```
tweet="La aplicaci\xf3n de un modelo educativo";
tweet = tweet.encode("utf-8");
```

Pero no he logrado que funcione.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Usas Python 2 o Python 3? Si es Python 2 ¿de que tipo (`type(tweet)`) es  `str` o `unicode`?

Comment: Es Python 2.7 y tipo 'str'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu cadena está codificada con ISO 8859-1/Latin-1 (`\xf3n`) en principio, no con UTF-8 (`\xc3\xb3n`). Por otro lado tienes una cadena de bytes y quieres obtener una **cadena unicode**, debes decodificar ([`decode`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode)) la cadena no, usar [`encode`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode):

```
>>> tweet = "La aplicaci\xf3n de un modelo educativo"
>>> tweet = tweet.decode("unicode_escape")
>>> print tweet
La aplicación de un modelo educativo
>>> type(tweet)
<type 'unicode'>
```

Podemos volver a codificar la cadena para volver a obtener un objeto `str` pero esta vez que use utf-8:

```
>>> tweet_utf_8 = tweet.encode("utf-8")
>>> type(tweet_utf_8)
<type 'str'>

# Si nuestra consola usa utf-8 podremos imprimir sin problemas
>>> print tweet_utf_8
La aplicación de un modelo educativo
```

Ejemplo online:

https://repl.it/@FJSevilla/decoding

Comment: ¡¡Funciona a la perfección!! Muchas gracias